# Merge many objects with equal position while sum up their attribute values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, fields-attributes, dissolve

I´m looking for a smart way to merge multiple line objects with the same geometry and same position in one layer while also sum up their attribute values. 
[image]
The result should be only one geometry (with the sum of all different object attributes)
To merge individual activated objects via expanded digitalizing tools won´t work, because the number of different overlaying objects is much too big to do this step by step. All other merging instruments combine either only two layers or don´t sum up the attribute values (i.e. mmqgis). Also v.dissolve seems not to give usable results. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying more tools it was pretty easy in the end:

1. Add the geometry attribute to each line object.
2. Use the aggregate function and group by the new `"perimeter"` attribute
3. Choose `"sum"`-option for the attribute where the data is in

**The result** is a vector layer with only one object at each line segment with summed up values.

Comment: Uuups, sorry! IMPORTANT! Better use the field calculator for 1. and create a unique attribute (i.e. "geom") for each object with "geom_to_wkt(  $geometry )". Otherwise it could happen that objects get aggregated that have the same perimeter but are located at different positions. Then use aggregate-function with group by geom-values. sorry again, too early too happy.